# Cache streamed video for next loops in Node.js

Tags: node.js, next.js

Basically, i have video background in my website, loops infinitely. To decrease initial load, i streamed the video. The website is built in Next.js.

```
<video autoPlay loop muted playsInline preload='none'>
  <source src='/api/video' type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

```
// pages/api/video

const range = req.headers.range || 'bytes=0-'
const fileName = 'video.webm'
const videoPath = path.resolve('public/assets/', fileName)
const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size

const chunkSize = 1 * 1e6
const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ''))
const end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, videoSize - 1)

const contentLength = end - start + 1

const headers = {
  'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Length': contentLength,
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
}
res.writeHead(206, headers)

const stream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end })
stream.pipe(res)
```

Everything is working fine. But i realized that video is again being downloaded for the next loops. So i want it to download initially and when it loops next time, i want (to maybe cache it) so that next loops it doesn't download again.

Answer (score 0):

it occurs to me too. lucky for me. i find a solution.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', './play', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {//请求成功
        var blob = this.response;
        $("#video-id").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

do this, when video get into next loop, the brower will get a 206 status.